# How to stop vim from opening inline in bash

Tags: bash, vim, xterm

I recently sourced my bashrc from another guy. It completely changed my environment. I managed to fix most of the things. But I really don't know how to fix this. Google didn't help as I don't know how to frame the question.

My vim now opens "inline" in the bash shell. meaning if I open vim, do some stuff and close it. the window stays there in the shell. So if I've opened vim 3 times in quick succession. and I scroll up I will see 3 vim snapshots within the terminal window. How do i make it go back to the original stance ? (Where, if i open and close vim 3 times, there will be only 3 prompts in bash and not the entire vim window)

I hope I was clear. 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try to comment out different things in your bashrc and check what line is behind this?

Comment: That behavior is usually defined by your terminal emlator: in iTerm on Mac OS X, you need to uncheck "Save lines to scrollback in alternate screen mode". You forgot to paste the content of that file in your question. Oh , and using someone else's config is *always* a bad idea.

Comment: `save lines in scrollback` has **nothing** to do with this problem. You have picked up some setting (probably an alias) that is opening vim in some way that prevents it from cleaning up after itself on close. As noted **never ever** blindly use someone else's config **ever**. You should validate what every line of your `.bashrc` does, otherwise you are asking for trouble. That being said, look through your current `.bashrc` and validate what each line it doing. If you had nothing but the default `.bashrc`, you can generally find the default for new users in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies and the strong condemnation against using somebody else's bashrc.  Couldn't help guys, I needed work done fast and I needed to have all the aliases that my new team was using. I followed Johan and found out soon enough (as romainl pointed out) that my terminal emulator was set to dtterm. I set it back to xterm and I got the desired behaviour. Next in my reading bucketlist : Terminal Emulators.

Comment: @Proteen: Please consider making your "EDIT ANSWER" an actual answer and accept it. This makes it directly visible that your question got an satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting TERM variable to xterm from dtterm solved the problem !

```
export TERM=xterm
```